# Get Greenwich Mean Time

Tags: java, android, timezone, gmt

**India Standard Time** (IST) is 5:30 hours (5 hours 30 minutes) ahead of Greenwich Mean Time. We show it as GMT+5.5.

Is there any way to find this value (in above case, value = 5.5) by time zone?

In my android app, I can get device time zone. But how can I get this value using device time zone?

Comment: Tip: Using decimal fractions for spans of time does not work well. I suggest you learn about the `ZoneOffset`, `ZoneId` for offset and time zone work, and learn about `Duration`, and `Period` classes for working with spans-of-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double timezoneval = 0.0;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(mn.Year(), mn.Month(), mn.Day(), mn.Hour(), mn.minute(),
                (int) mn.second());
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        boolean t = tz.inDaylightTime(cal.getTime());
        if (t)
            timezoneval = ((TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset())
                    / (60 * 60 * 1000D) + (TimeZone.getDefault()
                    .getDSTSavings() / (60 * 60 * 1000D)));
        else
            timezoneval = ((TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()) / (60 * 60 * 1000D));
```

You can try this code. This will give you the value of time zone. If you want different timezone value; just change
`TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();` 
to

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
        TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
```

It will work for you.

Comment: "Asia/Kolkata" can be replaced by different valid timezone string.

Comment: can i use `tz.getRawOffset()` instead of `TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()` ?

Comment: what is `mn` in your code ? `cal.set(mn.Year(), mn.Month(), mn.Day(), mn.Hour(), mn.minute(),
                (int) mn.second());`

Comment: sorry...you can just set calender ; dats all....mn is object of my own implemented class. That is not for your use. Sorry for not to mention.Thanks

Comment: It is safer to use TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() if you have to work with other timezone very frequently. at the same time you have to set TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
TimeZone.setDefault(tz); . Other wise you can use tz.getRawOffset();

Answer (score 1):

Check the Timezone class. The raw offset is what you want, in millisecond. You can easily convert it to value in hours.

```
long rawOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset()

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> how can a get this value using device time zone

```java
ZonedDateTime.
now(
    ZoneId.systemDefault()  // Or: ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata") 
)
.getOffset()
.toString()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/0ZPaJ0).

> +05:30

## *java.time*

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        int seconds = zdt.getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
        System.out.println(seconds);

        // If required, convert it into hours
        double hours = seconds / 3600.0;
        System.out.println(hours);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
19800
5.5
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
TimeZone.getDefault();
```

[getDefault()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) returns the timezone details of the current device. You can then call [getOffset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset%28long%29) to get the difference between UTC and this time zone.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 public class Sample {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        String dateStr = "2010-06-14 02:21:49-0400";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);

        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
        String newDateStr = sdf.format(date);

        System.out.println(newDateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

output should like this

2010-06-14 08:21:49 AM

Answer (score -1):

This is actually what i need.

```
double rawOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();

rawOffset = rawOffset / (60 * 60 * 1000);

System.out.println("rawOffset : " + rawOffset);
```